# Another basic question on list manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose you have a list of triples:

```
A = {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3}}
```

How do we find x such that z is the maximum?

Comment: See `MaximalBy[ A, Last]`

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to MMA SE!

There are lots of ways, but one is with `MaximalBy`. `MaximalBy[list, f]` returns a list of the elements `e` in `list` for which `f[e]` is maximal. Here, you'd want `f` to take the third part of the element; a function which does that can be written (anonymously) as `#[[3]] &`, with `#` being the "argument slot" and `&` indicating that the expression is a function. (Just explaining everything in case that's helpful.) In this case, that's equivalent to the built-in function `Last`, by the way.

Then `MaximalBy[A, #[[3]] &]` will give you a list like `{{xi,yi,zmax}, {xj, yi, zmax}, ...}` for however many instances of `zmax` there are. To take all the `x`'s, you can map (`f /@ list`, i.e. apply `f` to all elements of `list`) the function which takes the first element. We could use `#[[1]] &` or simply `First`. So, `First /@ MaximalBy[A, #[[3]] &]` will give a list of the `xi`.

If you know there's just one (or just want one), you can take e.g. `First` of the result, like `First[First /@ MaximalBy[A, #[[3]] &]]`.